# replace with bigger neighbor

Tags: arrays

I am trying to make a method that will replace the numbers in an array with the bigger of its two neighbors. So far I have this:

```
    public void replaceWithBigNeighbor(double[] array) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if(i != 0 && i != array.length-1)
            {
                double leftNeighbor = array[i-1];
                double rightNeighbor = array[i+1];
                if(leftNeighbor > rightNeighbor)
                {
                    array[i] = leftNeighbor; 
                }
                else if(leftNeighbor < rightNeighbor)
                {
                    array[i] = rightNeighbor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can't think of a way to stop the one biggest number from being used on every subsequent number because the loop makes it so the initial array is changed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I would like the input array to be modified. For example I want {3,14,12,15,2,4} to be changed to {3,12,15,12,15,4} instead of {3,14,15,15,15,4}

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery really just one extra `double`